# TensorFlow default precision mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I'm using TensorFlow 1.14 and testing TensorRT; as I see in the documentation, TensorRT support 3 precision modes: "FP32", "FP16", and "INT8". So I want to know what is the default precision mode of TensorFlow; I suppose it's FP32 but I'm not totally sure about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default precision of **weights** in tensorflow is 'float32', as can be seen in weight initialisation function documentation here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6bfbcf31dce9a59acfcad51d905894b082989012/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L527

However, inputs could be in multiple precision as supported by different layers used in model.

Now, mostly you would want to reduce size of model (which is formed by model weights) after training to be able to deploy. During that time, you could reduce precision of model weight to FP16.

Answer (score 3):

The default precision of TensorRT is **Float32**. See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#network_python)

The default precision of Tensorflow is also **Float32**. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/floatx)
You can confirm this by:
**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.floatx()
```

**output:**

```
'float32'
```

If you wish to change this behavior or use other precision:
You can use **set_floatx** method.

```
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
```

**Note:** It is not recommended to set this to float16 for training, as this will likely cause numeric stability issues.

Comment: Using `float16` is perfectly fine. You just have to remember to increase the size of every epsilon used in the implementation (e.g. in Adam, log, or div) as some default values might be too small for the underlying precision, leading to 0.0 values.

Comment: @runDOSrun See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_floatx#used-in-the-notebooks). It is written in official TensorFlow documentation. Also, can you elaborate more on increasing size of epsilon?

Comment: Thanks for the source! Several TF implementations of basic operations require adding a small number (usually called epsilon e) to avoid NaNs. The simplest example would be div(a,0) := a/0. We don't really want this to throw an Exception because this actually happens pretty frequently (especially in the Optimizer/Loss). Solution: div(a,b) := a/(b+e) where e=1e-7. However, 32bit gives you exactly 7 decimal digits of precision. If we decrease precision, we need to increase the episilons to avoid NaNs from popping up everywhere. I assume they'll add dynamic checks for this one day.