# InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:MatMul] name:

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, types

The data type of input_data is an array of numpy.float64 but the code still fails inside a tensorflow library because it's not a 'double'. Not sure how to remedy this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=100)
print("type(input_data):", type(input_data), "type(input_data[0]):", type(input_data[0]))

class ArtificialNeuron(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(1, 1)))
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(1,)))

    def __call__(self, x):
        return tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, self.w) + self.b)

neuron = ArtificialNeuron()

# Fails here: InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:MatMul] name: 
output_data = neuron(input_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown because you are mixing `float32` and `float64` tensors without conversion. By default `numpy` uses `float64` while TensorFlow uses `float32`. Normally the higher level modules perform the conversion, but I think you are using low-level building blocks, so you have to do the conversion yourself.

You can simply test this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.array([[1.0]], dtype=np.float64)
w = tf.zeros(shape=(1,1))
tf.matmul(x, w)

# => InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:MatMul]
# Changing np.float32 to np.float64 above the code works...
```

So you either have to convert your input to `float32` by using `np.float32(input_data)`, or use everywhere `float64` tensors. You might also change the default precision of TensorFlow to `float64` as described here: [TensorFlow default precision mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698608/tensorflow-default-precision-mode)

In short, to fix your code, replace `input_data` in the last line by `np.float32(input_data)` and `size=100` in the definition of `input_data` by `size=(100,1)`.

Comment: I understand your solution : am I just misinterpreting the diagnostic? "Expected to be a double but is a float" says to me that the data type I'm using is too small, but it's actually too wide?

Comment: The error says that `tf.matmul` expected the second argument (input `#1(zero-based)`, that is `self.w` which is `float`) to be the same as the first argument (`x` which is `double`). The problem is that the data types mismatch, which one is too small or wide is up to you to decide, and fix the problem by converting it.